# Public classes in custom framework

Tags: ios, xcode

In my custom framework, if i want to expose some classes/methods to swift or objective-c, i have to declare them as public, but with this method the classes and methods are exposed in the framework header.
Is there a way to prevent to expose the methods to framework header?

Comment: If you don't want to expose class' methods, then why do you want to expose class itself? What do you want to expose then? For what purpose?

Comment: the classes are exposed because they are used in the swift/objective-c code of other classes, what i want is continue to use these methods in objective-c/swift code, but i don't want to expose these classes in the general framework header, because in this case these methods can be called by who use my custom framework

Comment: Is your custom framework written in Swift or Objective-C?

Comment: Some classes are written in objective-c and other are written in swift, the problem is in objective-c classes that calls swift methods

Answer (score 1):

If your framework is written in Swift, then use Access Levels - public, open, internal, file-private or private - [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html). You probably want to use **internal**

If your framework is written in Objective-C, you can use forward declaration. Instead of writing

```
// ClassA.h

#import "ClassB.h"

@interface ClassA : NSObject

- (void)doSomethingWithClassB:(ClassB*)obj;

@end
```

Write

```
// ClassA.h

@class ClassB;

@interface ClassA : NSObject

- (void)doSomethingWithClassB:(ClassB*)obj;

@end

// ClassA.m

#import "ClassB.h"
```

If your `ClassA` doesn't inherit from `ClassB`, you can **forward declare** `ClassB` in you `ClassA` header - in the header you're not calling any methods from ClassB, you just use a pointer to it, so the compiler doesn't need to know the full signature of `ClassB`. Instead, you promise that you will include the full definition of `ClassB` before actually trying to use it.

Comment: if i declare a swift class as internal, it doesn't resolve my problem, the class is not added to the "module-Swift.h" file and is not exposed to the objective-c class

Comment: Exactly this is not an answer to the question, how did you solve it @blackstar26?